# Format USB Flash Drives with command prompt

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, prompt

How can I format ( delete all files ) an USB Flash Drives with the command prompt ?

I have the last version of Windows 10 and my USB Flash Drives is fat32.

Comment: It is similar bu not the same

Comment: just as a comment on "format ( delete all files )" - format does not delete your files, give your disk to me after format and I will get all your files back; if what you want is to ensure secure delete of those files, there is specific formatting required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy with `diskpart`:

- Press Windows key + X
- Select (Command Prompt (Admin)
- In the next windows write: `diskpart`
- In the new window that appears write: list disk
- Choose your USB drive ( careful!! check capacity if it matches your USB disk) by writing `select disk xx`, where xx is the corresponding disk
- After this, just the `format` command from there follow instructions and you done

Comment: as this is win 10 question I'm just curios - everybody suggests using diskpart - is really simple format command taken out from win10 commandline? I have not played with win 10 enough,- lack of time, but on my win7 just checked - format is still available.

Answer (score 1):

To format using command prompt first open command prompt in administrator mode. Type `diskpart` in command prompt and press `enter`. After that type `list disk` & `enter` and it will show you the list of available disks. Normally your operating system HDD will be `Disk 0` and USB will be `Disk 1` if no other storage device is attached however be extreme careful before proceeding to next step. Type `Select disk 1` and press `enter` after that type `format quick fat32 label=myusbdrive` & `enter` Then type `exit` and again `exit`.

P.S. If there is additional partition and you want to remove it then you can type `clean` before typing `format quick fat32 label=myusbdrive` also you can substitute `fat32` with `ntfs` if you wish.

Answer (score -1):

Formatting an USB flash drive from the command prompt is a simple process that can be achieved using the format command, which works for most version of Microsoft Windows (Windows 95 up to Windows 8.1).

Comment: it worked before Win95 as well :)

Comment: @androidrobo - How is exactly is it accomplished?  Provide detail specifics on how this accomplished.  Other answers seem to point to the process being more complicated then "just using the format command".  I know how to do it, others might not know how to do it, I am submitting this comment on the behalf of everyone who doesn't already know how to do it.